# What determines the name of registry entries under \Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItem?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2007

I'm trying to script a way to re-enable a specific Outlook add-in via the registry (Outlook UI isn't an option since it's locked down for users).

I know the general location I need to remove a reg entry is under: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItem`

I also know that the registry entries here contain binary values that relate to the add-in dll. I'm confused though on how the name of the registry entry is created.  Is it a static value?

In short, I'm wondering if I can reliably use the name of the registry entry to check if an add-in disabled or if I should assume that the name is random and subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very sure about the `Resiliency\DisabledItem` key, but I use Outlook, and I have a lot of Outlook add-ins, and I've even developed some Outlook add-ins, and I have never bothered with that particular key.

I always consulted the key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<Add-in Name>\
LoadBehavior = 0    REG_DWORD
```

0 Means the add-in is disabled.  A value of 3 means the add-in automatically starts when Outlook starts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx#LoadBehavior

This may or may not be relevant to you... I think this key may be for "application-level" add-ins only... but the only stuff I see in the `Resiliency\DisabledItem` key is binary goo, I don't know what it means, it's most likely not documented and not intended to be manually modified.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  My understanding is that LoadBehavior is used to control the add-in's "active/inactive" state where as this other entry controls what Outlook calls the "enabled/disabled" state of the add-in.  I've tried testing with various loadbehavior values and it doesn't seem to make a difference - if the add-in is marked as disabled in the `DisabledItem` key, Outlook leaves it off.